# Im making a Discord bot, but when the bot uses Rythm commands, nothing happens. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: python, discord, bots

When i use commands, it works. When my bot uses commands, it doesnt. Is there a way to get around this? Im making a command that plays the author's favourite song when used.
Heres the code for the command:

```
favj1='Radioactive'
favj2='Loonboon PvZ Remix'
favj3='Shallow'

@bot.command(name='fav', help='play your favourite song')
async def playfav(ctx):
    print(ctx.author.display_name)
    if ctx.author.display_name=='guy1':
        await ctx.send('!play '+ favj1)
    if ctx.author.display_name=='guy2':
        await ctx.send('!play '+ favj2)
    if ctx.author.display_name=='guy3':
        await ctx.send('!play '+ favj3)
```

Comment: Not completely sure about this, but I think by default, bot messages get filtered out to avoid infinite loops. Unfortunately don't know the answer off the top of my head.